# Markup or Trick? Nested forms

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, paperclip

There are interesting task: my active record '***Event***' entity can contain one '*Attachment*' PDF file. On the Create Event page, user can Upload this *attachment* BEFORE Submits that Event. Attachment uploads to Amazon via Ajax, progress-bar displays *etc blablabla*.
It should be displayed in_a_way:

```
= form_for @event do |e|
  = e.text_field :name

  = form_for @attach, :remote=>true, html=>{:multipart=>true} do |at|
    = at.file_field :pdf, :accept=>"pdf", :size=>"1"
    = at.submit

  = e.submit
```

Yes, this is just pseudo-code, and I don't mind how it can work, but the main idea is presents: **[Submit Attachment]** button should be placed **inside** the Event form.
*How I can implement it?* Maybe, just make some offset to nested Attachment form so it will be displayed inside Event form, or there are any others solutions?

......................................................[image: php_vs_rails]....................................................

Comment: What is the reason that you need the nested form submit in the outer form? Is this a visual requirement or something else?

Comment: It is just a visual requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: override form headers
This is a form for creating new event.
Inside this form, we need ajax file uploading.
There is a solution: mixing single form between two different types of submits: ajax(js) and html:

```
= form_for @event, html=>{:multipart=>true} do |e|
  = e.text_field :name

  = file_field_tag "attach[pdf]", :id=>"attach_pdf", :accept => "pdf", :maxlength => "200"
  = submit_tag "", :id => "ajax_submit", :style=>"display:none"

  = e.submit    <!-- id = "new_event_submit" -->

////////////////////////////
// before 'submits' call override functions:

$("#ajax_submit").click(function(){
    prepeareFormForAjax();
    return true;
});

$("#new_event_submit").click(function(){
  prepeareFormForHtml();
  return true;
});

//////////////////////////////
// to store original (previous, html) form data
var html_form_action = "";
var html_form_method = "";
///////////////////////////////

/* 
 * To ajax file upload:
 **/
function prepeareFormForAjax() {
  $("form").attr("data-remote", "true");
  $("form").attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");  

  html_form_action = $("form").attr("action");  // save old action
  $("form").attr("action", "/attach");            // I need /nors action

  //_method field is a hidden form field, maybe you have it too on the page:
  if ($('input[name="_method"]').length != 0) {
    html_form_method = $('input[name="_method"]').val();
    $('input[name="_method"]').val("post");
  }

}

function prepeareFormForHtml() {
  $("form").removeAttr("data-remote");
  $("form").removeAttr("enctype");
  if (html_form_action != "") {
    $("form").attr("action", html_form_action);
    html_form_action = "";
  }
  if (html_form_method != "") {
    $('input[name="_method"]').val(html_form_method);
    html_form_method = "";
  }
}

///////////////////////
```

Now, to upload file via AJAX use:

```
$("#ajax_submit").click();
```

any questions?